# Generate FORM using XML in asp.net MVC and Razor

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to generate dynamic forms and bind them with data from DB from an xml file. We have a desktop application with almost all logic in ms sql and We would like to make web interface(there are hundreds of forms which I hope to avoid to make them manually). I would like to make an universal controller who recieves an xml file and make all the calls to db and display data in view. Is this even possible in mvc4?

XML:

```
<eXaForm xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
xmlns:eXa="eXa"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="eXa file:/Z:/Projects/eXactSQL-WEB/eXactSchema.xsd">
<Name Type="Search">Product</Name>
<SqlQuery>
    <Query>select top 10 * from Product</Query>
</SqlQuery>
<Controls>
    <Control name="ID" type="Text" label="Šifra blaga" class="tekstbox">
        <HelpNote> (Ident)</HelpNote>
        <BoundField>bla_id</BoundField>
        <format>999999</format>
    </Control>
    <Control name="Description" type="Text" label="Opis" class="tekstbox">
        <HelpNote>Description of product</HelpNote>
        <BoundField>bla_genOpis</BoundField>
     </Control>
    <Control name="NeAktiven" type="Check" label="Neaktiven" class="checkbox">
        <BoundField>bla_neaktiven</BoundField>
    </Control>
</Controls>
```

So far I can display form successfully but I have problem to populate it with values. Can I somehow get data from model by name not to use model.products.bla_blago
RAZOR:

```
//get data from db. I think I need here some universal class that is build on runtime or could I just send sqldatareader to the view???
        @foreach (var controle in Model.products)
        {<tr>
          //read nodes from xml
           @foreach (XElement control in childList.Descendants("Control"))
           {

          //Check what type is control of: text,checbox
            switch (@control.Attribute("type").Value)
            {

                //if text display textbox and bind data???
                case "Text":

                    string HelpNote = control.Elements("HelpNote").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                    string BoundField= control.Elements("BoundField").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                  //can I somehow get the value from Model by name of the column? I can't hard coded it because in next foreach there should be value from next column                     
                <td>@Html.TextBox(control.Attribute("name").Value, **Model.product["BoundField"] ???**, new { Title = HelpNote })</td>

                      break;   
                case "Check":

                <td>@Html.CheckBox(control.Attribute("name").Value, ?????)</td>
                      break;
                default:
                <text>
                <h1>Default</h1>
                </text>
                      break;
            }

           }           

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successed with reflection.

```
 @foreach (var **controle** in Model.product)
        {<tr>

            @foreach (XElement control in childList.Descendants("Control"))
            {

                switch (@control.Attribute("type").Value)
                {

                    case "Text":
                        // Use the text block below to separate html elements from code
                        string HelpNote = control.Elements("HelpNote").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                        string value = control.Elements("BoundField").FirstOrDefault().Value;                           
                        var vrednost = **controle**.GetType().GetProperty(value).GetValue(**controle**, null);
```